# How to Achieve Smooth Expansion and Prevent Grid Row Gaps with Hidden Elements in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

I'm working on a web layout where I have a section containing visible and hidden content. I've implemented a button to expand the hidden content smoothly using a transition effect. However, I'm facing two main issues:

While the expandable functionality works, the transition effect isn't as smooth as I'd like it to be. I've applied a CSS transition to change the grid-template-rows property, but it's not providing the desired smoothness. How can I achieve a smoother transition effect when expanding the hidden content?

Grid Row-Gap Reservation: I'm using a grid layout for the hidden content, and even when elements are hidden, the row-gap seems to be reserving extra space for them, causing a visual gap in the layout. I want to prevent this row-gap reservation for hidden elements. How can I modify my CSS to ensure that the row-gap is only applied to visible elements and not to hidden ones?

Here's a simplified version of my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code:
https://codepen.io/korneliuszburian/pen/LYaqyvN

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const button = document.querySelector(".btn__expand");
  let currentIndex = 0;
  let hiddenGroups = document.querySelectorAll(".cards--hidden");

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (currentIndex < hiddenGroups.length) {
      hiddenGroups[currentIndex].classList.remove("cards--hidden");
      hiddenGroups[currentIndex].classList.add("cards--active");
      currentIndex++;
    }

    if (currentIndex >= hiddenGroups.length) {
      button.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.visible,
.cards--hidden {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #000;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item__title h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

.item__title p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.cards--hidden {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition: grid-template-rows 300ms ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cards--active {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.btn__expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="visible">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item__title">
          <h2>Visible Item 1 Title</h2>
          <p>Description for Visible Item 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Visible Item 2 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Visible Item 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Visible Item 3 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Visible Item 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cards--hidden">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item__title">
          <h2>Hidden Item 1 Title</h2>
          <p>Description for Hidden Item 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 2 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 3 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cards--hidden">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item__title">
          <h2>Hidden Item 1 Title</h2>
          <p>Description for Hidden Item 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 2 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 3 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn__expand">
    <span class="btn__label">Expand all data</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only added `display: grid` to `.cards--hidden`, while it changes to `.cards--visible`, the container becomes `block`, so `grid-template-rows: 1fr` losts its effect and its transition is also lost.

You could move these rules to the general selector `.cards`, to allow the transition work as intended

```
.cards {
  display: grid;
  transition: grid-template-rows 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const button = document.querySelector(".btn__expand");
  let currentIndex = 0;
  let hiddenGroups = document.querySelectorAll(".cards--hidden");

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (currentIndex < hiddenGroups.length) {
      hiddenGroups[currentIndex].classList.remove("cards--hidden");
      hiddenGroups[currentIndex].classList.add("cards--active");
      currentIndex++;
    }

    if (currentIndex >= hiddenGroups.length) {
      button.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.visible,
.cards--hidden {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #000;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item__title h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

.item__title p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  transition: grid-template-rows 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.cards--hidden {
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn__expand {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* hide the wrapper content */
.cards--hidden .wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

/* add gap to visible items */
.visible, .cards--active {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="visible">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item__title">
          <h2>Visible Item 1 Title</h2>
          <p>Description for Visible Item 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Visible Item 2 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Visible Item 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Visible Item 3 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Visible Item 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cards--hidden">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item__title">
          <h2>Hidden Item 1 Title</h2>
          <p>Description for Hidden Item 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 2 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 3 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cards--hidden">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item__title">
          <h2>Hidden Item 1 Title</h2>
          <p>Description for Hidden Item 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 2 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <h2>Hidden Item 3 Title</h2>
        <p>Description for Hidden Item 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn__expand">
    <span class="btn__label">Expand all data</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Nice, way smoother, but you still are reserving space for hidden elements.

Comment: It was showing in the original example, do you want to hide the contents initially instead? I've updated the answer.

Comment: It's basically in my question 'Prevent Grid Row Gaps with Hidden Elements in CSS'

Comment: Ah, I must've missed that part, but I'm not quite sure about the effect you want to achieve, is the updated result what you wanted?

Comment: I just want the items, to not preserve space if they're 'hidden'. As you can see there are extra spacing, and they're visible, even without expanding them. Perfect scenerio is that, items are only visible and reserving space, when user want to expand the data.

@edit
Easy solution is to move the button out of the wrapper, and instead of using any gaps, we can apply on active item margin-top.